# Call a method of another class that has another class extended

Tags: java, class, methods, call, extends

How to call a method of another class that has another class extended?

I have two classes:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    public void whatever() {
        // whatever
    }
}

public void AnotherClass implements Listener {
    // whatever
}
```

When I try to call a method of Main in AnotherClass:

```
public class AnotherClass implements Listener {
    Main main = new Main();

    main.whatever();
}
```

It is not working but when I call a method of a function that does not extends something it works fine.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: it is not working! what do you mean by that? any errors?

Comment: public void AnotherClass implements Listener { <---- what is this.Method with implements?

Comment: "method of a function that does not extends something" <---- What is this, method with extends?

Comment: Okay strange. I solved the problem by just not extend JavaPlugin in a third class. It seems like everything is working then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues I see.

```
public void AnotherClass implements Listener
```

You can't have a `void` class.

You can't have two `public` classes in one file.

Your class declaration should look like this

```
class AnotherClass implements Listener
```

You are also calling `main.whatever()` from outside any method, which as far as I know will not work, unless it's in a `static` block.  You need call methods from within other methods.

```
class AnotherClass implements Listener {

    public void something() {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.whatever();
    }
}
```